# Python Selenium Scraping inconsistent Fields

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am scraping some data from a website, and sometimes they display the milage, other times they display MPG's in the vehicle descriptions 
here is the HTML

I was using xpath and was going to simply go in order

Here is the relevant part :

```
    def init_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver


def scrape(driver):

    #Tymm = year make model All three attributes are in the Header, Parse and separate before insterting to SQL
    ymm_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="compareForm"]/div/div/ul/li/div/div/h3')
    engine_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="compareForm"]/div/div/ul/li/div/div/div[3]/dl[1]/dd[1]')
    trans_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="compareForm"]/div/div/ul/li/div/div/div[3]/dl[1]/dd[2]')
    milage_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="compareForm"]/div/div/ul/li/div/div/div[3]/dl[1]/dd[3]')
```

Since the element's order is not the same for all vehicles, I need to write it so it can retrieve the text after the title i desire.

Here is the HTML after copying HTML on chrome from the element inspection:

```
  <div class="description">
    <dl> <dt>Engine:</dt> <dd>2.5L I-5 cyl<span class="separator">,</span>
    </dd> <dt>Transmission:</dt> <dd>Manual<span class="separator">,</span></dd> <dt>Mileage:</dt> <dd>37,171 miles<span class="separator">,</span></dd> <dt>MPG Range:</dt> <dd>22/31<span class="separator">,</span></dd></dl><dl class="last"> <dt>Exterior Color:</dt> <dd>Reflex Silver Metallic<span class="separator">,</span></dd> <dt>Interior Color:</dt> <dd>Titan Black<span class="separator">,</span></dd> <dt>Stock #:</dt> <dd>P3229</dd></dl> <span class="ddc-more">More<span class="hellip">…</span></span> 
<div class="calloutDetails">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li class="certified" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><div class="badge "><img class="align-center" src="https://static.dealer.com/v8/global/images/franchise/white/en_US/logo-certified-volkswagen.gif?r=1356028132000" alt="Certified"></div></li><li class="carfax" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><a href="http://www.carfax.com/cfm/ccc_displayhistoryrpt.cfm?partner=DLR_3&amp;vin=3VWHX7AT1EM600723" class="badge carfax-one-owner pointer" target="_blank"><img class="align-center" src="https://static.dealer.com/v8/global/images/franchise/white/logo-certified-carfax-one-owner-lrg.png?r=1405027620000" alt="Carfax One Owner"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="hproductDynamicArea"></div>
</div>
```

Basically I need to be searching for the text after the title instead of numbering the xpaths.

My year make and model are all in the same element " tag, Could you point me in the right direction or suggest a library split head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, with xpath you can use contains, like this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//dt[contains(text(),'Engine')]')
```

it looks cleaner, easier to use and more robust.

Second, read about xpath following-sibling, preceding-sibling, parent and ancestor. It will help you to build neat xpath locators:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//dt[contains(text(),'Engine:')]/following-sibling::dd')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//dt[contains(text(),'Transmission:')]/following-sibling::dd')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//dt[contains(text(),'Mileage:')]/following-sibling::dd')
```

Above xpaths will work no matter which order your html elements are located in.

Comment: Thank you, I will do so, I had to change to double quotes but it works like a charm. I also will loop each Car one by one to avoid discrepancy.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again I am having a hard time looping through the web elements:                            def scrape(driver):
    cars = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="description"]')
    for car in cars:    
        engine = car.find_element_by_xpath("//dt[contains(text(),'Engine')]/following-sibling::dd")
        mileage = car.find_element_by_xpath("//dt[contains(text(),'Mileage')]/following-sibling::dd")

        print (mileage.text, engine.text)

Comment: def scrape(driver):
    cars = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="description"]')
    for car in cars:    
        engine = car.find_element_by_xpath("//dt[contains(text(),'Engine')]/following-sibling::dd")
        mileage = car.find_element_by_xpath("//dt[contains(text(),'Mileage')]/following-sibling::dd")

        print (mileage.text, engine.text)